# Weird windows explorer bug

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

Any idea what's causing this weird windows explorer bug, to appear black background for folders.

[image]

Is this due to change of some system settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed by making use of a simple .bat file reset thumbnail cache files. For that purpose, open the Notepad and then copy and paste the following code:

```
@echo off 

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe
timeout 2 /nobreak>nul
echo.
DEL /F /S /Q "%LocalAppData%\IconCache.db"
DEL /F /S /Q "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\iconcache_*.db"
DEL /F /S /Q "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_*.db"
 
timeout 2 /nobreak>nul
start explorer.exe
```

Save the file in .bat format. Double click to run the program. This will also restart Windows explorer, so your screen might go blank for some moments. After that, you should no longer face this issue again.

For more information and methods, see this: [How to Fix Black Background Behind Folder Icons in Windows 10](https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-black-background-behind-folder-icons-windows10/)

Comment: It takes a long time for this to get executed. Once the window goes blank, it never really comes back, until I manually start it.

Comment: Check the link that I've attached. It list out another method of achieving the same. That might work for you.

Comment: Had to manually delete the files and it worked. Thanks for the link!